# Cargar datos de modal a campos de texto

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, web

me gustaría que me ayuden con un problema que tengo:

- En un modal tengo una tabla con los datos de unos materiales
- En una columa tengo el boton de insertar,
- Al hacer click en tal botón, se debe ocultar el modal e insertar "Código y Material a los campos de texto del formulario"
- Lo único que no consigo hacer es copiar los datos de código y material a los campos de textos.

De antemano agradezco la ayuda, les muestro imagenes para mejor comprensión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por si le sirve a alguien, ya lo he logrado. Pongo el codigo aqui, es un poco desordenado, pero funciona:

```
<tbody>
<?php
$tab = 0;
//include('conexion.php');
$sqlb ='SELECT COUNT(*) FROM materiales';
$canfilasb = mysql_query($sqlb, $conexion);
$sqlb = 'SELECT ma.codigo, ma.descripcion, mag.magnitud, ma.precio_Uni FROM 
materiales ma, magnitud mag WHERE ma.cod_magnitud = mag.codigo ORDER BY 
ma.codigo ASC';
$resultadob = mysql_query($sqlb, $conexion);

$contadorb = 0;
$contadorc = 0;

while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultadob, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
 $codigob = $fila['codigo'];
 $descripcionb = $fila['descripcion'];
 $magnitudb = $fila['magnitud'];

 $contadorb = $contadorb + 1;

?>
<tr class="">
<td><?php echo $codigob ;  ?></td>
<td><?php echo $descripcionb ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $magnitudb ; ?></td>
<td>
<form name="buscaMaterial<?php echo $contadorb;  ?>" method="post" 
class="form-horizontal">
<input type = "hidden" id = "contadorc" name = "contadorc" value="<?php echo 
$contadorc ;?>"/>

<button name="btnModificar<?php echo $contadorb;  ?>" class="btn btn- 
default" data-toggle="button" onclick="insertarMat(<?php echo $contadorc ;? 
>)" >
<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i>
</button>

<script>
  function insertarMat(x){
  //var x = document.getElementById('contadorc').value;
  $("#campo1").val(document.getElementById('editable- 
  sample').tBodies[0].rows[x].cells[0].innerHTML);
  $("#campo2").val(document.getElementById('editable- 
  sample').tBodies[0].rows[x].cells[1].innerHTML);
  $("#campo4").val(document.getElementById('editable- 
  sample').tBodies[0].rows[x].cells[2].innerHTML);

  //$("#campo1").val(document.getElementById('codigoins').value);
  //$("#campo2").val(document.getElementById('materialins').value);
  //$("#campo4").val(document.getElementById('magnitudins').value);

 $('#myModal').modal('hide');
 }
 </script>
 </form>

 </td>
</tr>
<?php
$contadorc = $contadorc + 1;
}

?>
</tbody>
```